# Power Automate Cloud - OneDrive When a file is created Trigger Condition

Tags: triggers, onedrive, power-automate

I'm using the OneDrive when a file is created trigger in my flow. I want to set a trigger condition that will only trigger if the file type is .xlsx

**I tried the following condition:**
@contains(triggerOutputs()?['headers/x-ms-file-name-encoded'], 'xlsx')

**I get the following error:**
InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions for trigger 'When_a_file_is_created' at line '1' and column '37225': 'The template language function 'endswith' expects its first parameter to be of type string. The provided value is of type 'Null'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#endswith for usage details.'.

I did some research on-line and it appears to be due to the OneDrive dynamic selector "File name" being encoded, but I wasn't able to find any solutions for working around this issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [base64tostring](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#base64tostring) function to turn it into a readable string.

Try an trigger condition expression like below

```
@endswith(base64tostring(triggerOutputs()?['headers/x-ms-file-name-encoded']), '.xlsx')
```